# Angularjs watch on Service Variable from directive best Practice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i'm trying to display a Bootstrap modal Dialog when a Variable in a Service is changed. 
I'm currently doing this with broadcast. I'm new to angular so any help to improve my code is appreciated.
This Code works but i wanted to know if this is the correct way to do this.

My Service:

```js
utils.service('UtilsService', function ($rootScope) {   
    this.objectToDelete = "";
    this.deleteMessage = "";
    this.DeleteObject = function (object, message) {
        this.objectToDelete = object;
        this.deleteMessage = message;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('objectChanged', this.objectToDelete);
    }

});
```

My Directive:

```js
verwaltungApp.directive('deletedialog', ['UtilsService', function (UtilsService) {
return {
    restrict: 'E',
    controller: function ($scope, $attrs, UtilsService) {           
        $scope.$on("objectChanged", function (event, args) {
            if (UtilsService.objectToDelete) {
                $scope.ObjectToDelete = UtilsService.objectToDelete;
                $scope.Message = UtilsService.deleteMessage;
               $('#modalErrorDialog').modal('show');                   
            }
        });
        $scope.DeleteObject = function () {
            $scope.ObjectToDelete.Delete();
            $scope.ObjectToDelete = null;
            $('#modalErrorDialog').modal('hide');
        }

        $scope.Cancel = function () {
            $scope.ObjectToDelete = null;
            $('#modalErrorDialog').modal('hide');

        }         
    },      
    templateUrl: '/shared/DeleteDialog'
};
}]);
```

I tried it with $watch before but that did not work for me. 
The main thing i want to do is to place this directive on my Layout Page so i can call it from any controller with an object i want to delete.